# Strange error this.setState in React

Tags: reactjs

I am building a fairly simple blog app in React. I am getting a very strange error from this React component. Here is the error:

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
toggleEditing
src/blogform.js:11
   8 |     }
   9 | }
  10 | toggleEditing(){
> 11 |     this.setState({
  12 |         editing: !this.state.editing
  13 |     })
  14 | }
```

Here is the component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class BlogForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
            editing: false
        }
    }
    toggleEditing(){
        this.setState({
            editing: !this.state.editing
        })
    }
    render(){ 
        if(this.state.editing){
            return (
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={e => {
                        e.preventDefault(); 
                        this.props.onAdd(this.inputText.value)
                        }}>
                        <input ref={input => this.inputText = input} />
                    </form>
                </div>
            )
        } 
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={ this.toggleEditing }>New Post</button>
            </div>
        )

    }
}
```

Any thoughts? It seems to be upset by this.setState, but I can't quite see what is wrong with the statement.

Comment: Suggested reading: https://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/

Comment: <button onClick = { this.toggleEditing.bind(this) }>New Post</button> you forgot to add bind on your onClick event

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind the function in your `constructor()` so it maintains the correct `this` value.

You can do that by adding the following in your constructor:

`this.toggleEditing = this.toggleEditing.bind(this);`

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

1. use `bind` in your `constructor`, as mentioned in the other answer.

   `this.toggleEditing = this.toggleEditing.bind(this)`
2. use `bind` in your `onClick` handler.

   `onClick={ this.toggleEditing.bind(this) }`
3. use an arrow function as the callback function.

   `onClick={() => this.toggleEditing() }`

Tell me if you want an explanation for any of them.